# Lifting properties of morphisms in category of sets

Tags: category-theory, morphism

Let $f:A\to B,g:C\to D$ be morphisms in a category $\mathcal C.$ We denote $f\perp g$ if in every commutative square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> C\\
@VfVV @VVgV \\
B @>>> D
\end{CD}$$
there is a unique $d:B\to C$ making both triangles commute. Moreover, for a class $X\subseteq\operatorname{Mor}(\mathcal C)$ denote $X^\perp=\{g\mid\forall f\in X:f\perp g\},{}^\perp X=\{f\mid\forall  g\in X:f\perp g\}$. Now,I want to show that in $\mathbf{Set}$ we have $Epi^\perp=Mono$. I think this should be somehow easy but I got lost in universal quantifiers. Inclusion "$\subseteq$" should follow from
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>u>> C\\
@V{\text{id}}VV @VVgV \\
A @>>> D
\end{CD}$$
where the unique diagonal is $u$ $\color{blue}{\text{(correct?)}}$ but what about the other? I don't even know what exactly I should prove. Given a mono $g:C\to D$ such that every commutative square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>>> C\\
@VVV @VVgV \\
\circ @>>> D
\end{CD}$$
has a unique diagonal $\circ\to C,$ then (every) $\bullet\to\circ$ is an epi?

Comment: To show $Mono \subseteq Epi^\perp$, shouldn't it be equivalent to show that for every epi $f$ and mono $g$, we have $f \perp g$?

Comment: As for the inclusion $Epi^\perp \subseteq Mono$, my thinking is tending more towards applying the condition with epimorphisms of the form $\operatorname{id}_A + \operatorname{id}_A : A \sqcup A \to A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to make your first diagram work. Instead here is an idea from @DanielSchepler. If you have two morphisms $f_1$, $f_2:A\to C$ such that $gf_1 = gf_2$, then consider the commuting diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A\sqcup A @>f_1\sqcup f_2>> C\\
@V\lambda VV @VVgV \\
A @>gf_1=gf_2>> D
\end{CD}$$
where $\lambda$ is the map which "forgets" which side of the disjoint union a given $x\in A$ came from.

By assumption, this has a unique diagonal $d:A\to C$ for which the diagram still commutes. The top triangle commutes, i.e. $f_1\sqcup f_2 = d\circ\lambda$. By looking at the two halves of $A\sqcup A$, we can see that $f_1 = d = f_2$.

Conversely, if $g$ is a mono, consider an epi $f$ in the commuting diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>u_1>> C\\
@VfVV @VVgV \\
B @>u_2>> D
\end{CD}$$
The claim is that regardless of the choice of $f$, $u_1$, $u_2$ here, there exists a unique $d:B\to C$ such that the diagram still commutes when $d$ is added. (This is different from your interpretation of the $\supseteq$ direction! If you want to try answering the problem yourself, starting from the correct statement, stop reading here.)

Finally, we construct $d$. Up til now we haven't actually used any properties of **Set**; now we need to. Consider that $\text{Im}(u_2) \subseteq \text{Im}(g)$ as subsets of $D$; this must be true since otherwise the diagram couldn't commute (and because $f$ is epi). But then since $g$ is mono we can take $g^{-1}:\text{Im}(u_2)\to C$ as a well-defined function, and write $d = g^{-1}u_2$. The fact that the resulting diagram commutes is pretty-much immediate from this definition of $d$.

Comment: I like to point that to $g^{-1]$ we're using the axiom of choice, and in fact that's why such (epi,mono) factorizations elsewhere, namely in topoi equipped with something analogous to choice.

Comment: @DanielSchepler the claim of the upper triangle commuting is $u_1 = df = g^{-1}u_2f$, which is true because the original diagram was commutative.

Comment: @DanielPlácido Since $g$ is a mono, forming $g^{-1}$ only requires the much weaker criterion of "unique choice": that if singletons pull back to singletons, then a choice function exists.  (As opposed to the full axiom of choice which weakens the required hypothesis to singletons pulling back to nonempty sets.)  And unique choice is totally fine in any topos - or also in any abelian category, for that matter.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ah! I think you are correct. The top triangle commuting is equivalent to saying $f_1=f_2$, i..e. my first paragraph is assuming the hypothesis and is wrong.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I used your suggestion to look at $A\sqcup A$ and I think I have a working argument now. Apologies if you were trying to give a hint and I gave away the answer.

Comment: Am I wrong, or the very same proof (starting with "Conversely") gives us also inclusion $Epi\subseteq{}^\perp Mono$?

Comment: @byk7 I don't see it. Assuming $g$ is mono we explicitly construct a $d$ (and we use the **Set** definition of mono, i.e. $g$ is an injection, rather than the category-theoretic definition). I don't see how to go from having such a $d$ to $g$ being mono, even in **Set**.

Comment: Yes, $Epi \subseteq {}^\perp Mono$ is equivalent to $Mono \subseteq Epi^\perp$ - essentially the two are just gotten from each other by reversing the order of quantifiers between $\forall f \in Epi$ and $\forall g \in Mono$.  (On the other hand, to show ${}^\perp Mono \subseteq Epi$, you would need to dualize the argument that $Epi^\perp \subseteq Mono$ - that would involve considering diagonal maps $\Delta_C : C \to C \times C$ in the role of $g$.)